# Confusion on OpenIddict

Tags: visual-studio-2017, openiddict

In my .csproj file I have the following:

```
    <!-- OpenIdDict -->
<!-- <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="1.0.0" /> -->
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="1.0.0-rtm-1063" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0-rtm-1063" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="1.0.0-rtm-1063" />
```

The Aspnnet.Security.Oauth.Validation is commented out on the advice of Pinpoint. By doing this I got my project to work but I was getting an error because the logon request was missing the 'client-id' parameter. On googling this I learned that I had to add the following code:

```
options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
options.DisableScopeValidation();
```

But this implies I am using version 2 of OpenIddict. I am happy to do this, but obviously these PackageReference tags are not correct. I am using the latest of VS2017. What SHOULD I be including in the project and which of  those PackageReference elements can be removed?

Comment: Actually no, these 2 methods are available in OpenIddict 1.0 RC3 and RTM (for ASP.NET Core 1.x): you don't have to migrate to 2.0 to use them.

Comment: I understand that, but as I understood it, it wasn't the default then. But without them 'client-id' wasn't a required parameter. I thought later versions demanded client-id by default.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the version scheme: both OpenIddict 1.0 and 2.0 are updated at the same pace. The only difference is that 1.0 targets ASP.NET Core 1.0 and 2.0 ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Ah, that now makes perfect sense!